# What is a "Live object" in "Object Lifecycle Management"?

Tags: object, google-cloud-storage, lifecycle

I am trying to understand "Object Lifecycle Management" in https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle

The concept of "live object" appears to be central to the subject, but it is not defined.
What is a "live object" exactly?

("live data" has a different meaning in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup#Live_data)

Comment: GCS documentation refers to "live object" all over the place, but doesn't define it anywhere :/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A live object is one that is not an archived generation.
If you enable [versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning) on a bucket, deleting or overwriting an object leaves an archived generation. Lifecycle Management gives you the option to operate only archived (or only live) generations.

Comment: Thanks Mike, that makes more sense. The [Object Lifecycle Management](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle) page only uses the word "version". What is the difference between "generation" and "version"?

Comment: "generation" and "version" are synonymous.